# How to find a point on map with GPS coordinates?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, gps, gps-track-editor

I need to import data from my smarphone using GPS.

The area is north of Italy so I believe I have to choose SR: WGS84 for the new project, haven't I?

Data are collected in the following csv table:

- id - x - y
- 120 - 45,0770533 - 7,6610054
- 124 - 46,115925 - 12,098411

I use QGIS 2.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the coordinates stored in an X field and in an Y field, you can define them when you import your file.
When you load a delimited text (CSV), there is the following line where you define where the geometry is stored :

[image: csv]